# gradient of an axis symmetric vector field in cylindical coordiantes

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, polar-coordinates

I am trying to calculate with a general approach the *gradient of  an axis symmetric vector field*  in *cylindrical coordinates* and then express it in *cartesian coordinates*.

First I write my vector field in cylindircal coordinates as
$$\mathbb{f} = [f_\rho(\rho,\phi,z),f_\phi(\rho,\phi,z),f_z(\rho,\phi,z)]^T$$
then I consider that it is axis symmetric so
$$\mathbb{f} = [f_\rho(\rho,z),f_\phi(\rho,z),f_z(\rho,z)]^T$$

The gradient of a scalar function $g=g(\rho,\phi,z)$ in cylindrical coordinates is $$\small \nabla g  = [\frac{\partial g}{\partial \rho} \mathbb, \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial g}{\partial \phi}, \frac{\partial g}{\partial z}]$$
but the gradient of a vector field in cylindrical coordinates seems to be far more complicated:
$$ 
\small
\frac{\partial ( f_\rho,f_\phi,f_z)}{\partial ( \rho,\phi,z)} =\left[
\begin{array}{clc}
\frac{\partial f_\rho}{\partial \rho} &   
\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial f_\rho}{\partial \phi}  - \frac{f_\phi}{\rho} &
\frac{\partial f_\rho}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial f_\phi}{\partial \rho} &   
\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial f_\phi}{\partial \phi}  + \frac{f_\rho}{\rho}&
\frac{\partial f_\phi}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial f_z}{\partial \rho} &   
\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial f_z}{\partial \phi} &
\frac{\partial f_z}{\partial z} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
*First Question:*   Where $\frac{f_\phi}{\rho}$ and $\frac{f_\rho}{\rho}$ additional terms come from?

OK, let's move on and consider the gradient of the transformation from cylindrical to cartesian as
$$ 
\small
\frac{\partial ( \rho,\phi,z)}{\partial ( X,Y,Z)} =\left[
\begin{array}{clc}
cos(\phi) &   
sin(\phi) &
0 \\
-sin(\phi) &   
cos(\phi) &
0 \\
0 &   
0 &
1 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

*Secon Question*:
My idea at the end is to multiply the two matrix in a sort of chain rule way in order to obtain the gradient in cartesian coordinates 
$$
\frac{\partial ( f_\rho,f_\phi,f_z)}{\partial ( X,Y,Z)} =\frac{\partial ( f_\rho,f_\phi,f_z)}{\partial ( \rho,\phi,z)} \frac{\partial ( \rho,\phi,z)}{\partial ( X,Y,Z)}
$$
Is this procedure correct.?
Thanks

Comment: You need to carefully distinguish between gradients and derivatives (since the metric is non-trivial) and between tangent vectors expressed in the coordinate basis $\partial/\partial \rho, \partial/\partial \theta, \partial/\partial z$ and those expressed in the "unit" basis $\partial/\partial \hat\rho, \partial/\partial \hat\theta, \partial/\partial \hat z$. These two factors account for the extra terms.